# Comparing counts of relatively prime integers within a finite set

Tags: inequality, prime-numbers, primorial

I am working on an approach to [Legendre's Conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_conjecture) that depends on the following result being true (where $p$ is any prime, $n$ is any integer where $p \nmid n$):

$$c_p(p,x) \ge c_p(n,x)$$

I am not sure that it is always true but I am unable to find a counter example.  I am starting with the case where $p=3$ and $n=5$.

Let:

- $f(x) = \prod\limits_{p\text{ prime & }p | x}p$
- $p_n$ be the $n$th prime
- $p\#$ be the [primorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primorial) of $p$
- $v(x) = \dfrac{(x+1)\#}{f(x^2+x)}$
- gcd$(a,b)$ be the [greatest common divisor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor) of $a$ and $b$.
- $c_p(n,x) = $ the count of integers $0\le t$ such that $pt+n < x$ and gcd$(x^2+x,pt+n)=1$

Here's my question:

Given:

- $x \ge 7$
- $x \equiv 1 \pmod 3$
- $15 | v(x)$

Does it always follow that:

$$c_3(3,x) \ge c_3(5,x)$$

Here are some examples:

- $x=7$

> - $v(7) = \dfrac{8\#}{f(56)} = \dfrac{7\#}{14} = 15$
> - $c_3(3,7) = 1$ which consists of $\{3\}$
> - $c_3(5,7) = 1$ which consists of $\{5\}$

- $x=13$

> - $v(13) = \dfrac{14\#}{f(182)} = \dfrac{13\#}{182} = 165$
> - $c_3(3,13) = c_3(3,7)+1$ which consists of $\{3,9\}$
> - $c_3(5,13) = c_3(5,7)+1$ which consists of $\{5,11\}$

- $x=16$

> - $v(16) = \dfrac{17\#}{f(272)} = \dfrac{17\#}{34} = 15,015$
> - $c_3(3,16) = c_3(3,13)+1$ which consists of $\{3,9,15\}$
> - $c_3(5,16) = c_5(3,13)$ which consists of $\{5,11\}$

Does it always follow that $c_3(3,x) \ge c_3(5,x)$?  Can someone find a counter example?

Comment: Is $x = 76$ a valid counter-example? I'll post my code as an answer soon. For reference, $c_3(3, 76) = 9$ (with the solutions $\{3, 9, 15, 27, 39, 45, 51, 69, 75 \}$), and $c_3(5, 76) = 10$ (with the solutions $\{5, 17, 23, 29, 41, 47, 53, 59, 65, 71\}$).

Comment: Awesome!  Thanks very much!  I suspected that there was a counter example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote some code in `Julia` to search for cases where the condition $c_3(3, x) \geq c_3(5, x)$ is false (essentially a brute-force approach). I'm posting this as an answer because I think some of the optimizations I made to the problem while writing this code might be useful in tackling similar problems. Here's a snippet of the code I've written that defines the relevant functions:

```
f(x::Int64)::Int64 = prod([p for p in primesieve(x) if mod(x, p) == 0])

primorial(x::Int64)::Int64 = prod(primesieve(x))

v(x::Int64)::Int64 = primorial(x + 1) / f(x^2 + x)

cₚ(p::Int64, n::Int64, x::Int64)::Int64 = 
length([t for t = 0:floor(Int64, (x - n)/p) if gcd(x^2 + x, p*t + n) == 1])
```

These functions are defined in a fairly straightforward way, almost exactly as described in the question (the `primesieve(x)` method is an implementation of the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) that generates the list of primes less than `x`). I initially attempted to search for counter-examples using the following code:

```
for x = 7:3:10000
    if v(x) % 15 == 0
        if cₚ(3, 3, x) < cₚ(3, 5, x)
            println(x)
        end
    end
end
```

Although this code correctly implemented all the necessary constraints, it did not run because the value of `v(x)` was out of the bounds of the `Int64` type for some of the larger values of `x` (this is not surprising, since the `primorial` function grows rapidly). This called for an alternative way to check the condition $15 \vert v(x)$ (or equivalently, $v(x) \equiv 0 \pmod{15}$).

The number $v(x)$ is a ratio of two other numbers: $\#(x+1)$ - the product of all the primes less than $x+1$, and $f(x^2 + x) = f(x\cdot (x+1))$ - the [radical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radical_of_an_integer) (largest square-free factor) of $x\cdot (x+1)$. The numerator of this fraction is always divisible by $15 = 3\cdot 5$, since it is required that $x \geq 7$. Checking $15 \vert v(x)$ therefore becomes equivalent to asking whether $15$ **does not** divide the number $f(x\cdot (x+1))$.

Although this simplification alone is enough to avoid the integer overflow, one can optimize the code even further - the condition $15 \nmid f(y)$ is equivalent to $3 \nmid f(y) \land 5 \nmid f(y)$. Further, $p \nmid f(y)$ is equivalent to $p \nmid y$, for any prime $p$. For $y = x^2 + x$, the conditions become $3 \nmid (x\cdot (x + 1))$ and $5 \nmid (x\cdot (x + 1))$. Since $x$ is required to be of the form $x \equiv 1 \pmod{3}$, the first condition is already satisfied. It suffices to check only the second condition $5 \nmid (x\cdot (x + 1))$, which is true for $x \equiv 1, 2, 3 \pmod{5}$.

The code can be modified to:

```
for x = 7:3:1000
    if !(x % 5 in [0, 4])
        if cₚ(3, 3, x) < cₚ(3, 5, x)
            println(x)
        end
    end 
end
```

This is a lot more efficient computationally and does not require any function other than $c_p(n, x)$ to be defined.

**Edit:** Some of the counter-examples found by this program are $76, 208, 322, 391, 406, 412, 436, 493, \text{ and } 496$.